# ansible run multiple commands with mutiple variables

Tags: ansible

I'm having the folowing ansible task:

```
      - name: Task1
        command: "{{ item }}"
        with_dict:
            - { key1: "aaa", key2: "aaa-file"}
            - { key1: "bbb", key2: "bbb-fie"}
            - ...
        loop:
            - cd /home/{{ dict.key1 }}
            - rm -f {{ dict.key2 }}
```

It's just a concocted example but what I'm trying to achieve is the following:

run all commands with the first entry `values` from `with_dict`, then run all commands with the second entry values from the `with_dict` etc.
I've looked over `with_nested`, but not sure if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to perform this.

**First : one command line**

```yaml
      - name: Task1
        command: "cd /home/{{ item.key1 }} && rm -f {{ item.key2 }}"
        with_items:
          - key1: "aaa"
            key2: "aaa-file"
          - key1: "bbb"
            key2: "bbb-fie"
          - ...
```

If you really wants to perform a `cd` command, use this :

```yaml
      - name: Task1
        command: "rm -f {{ item.key2 }}"
        args:
          chdir: "/home/{{ item.key1 }}"
        with_items:
          - key1: "aaa"
            key2: "aaa-file"
          - key1: "bbb"
            key2: "bbb-fie"
          - ...
```

**Second : use two tasks**

```yaml
      - name: Task1
        command: "cd /home/{{ item.key1 }}"
        with_items:
          - key1: "aaa"
            key2: "aaa-file"
          - key1: "bbb"
            key2: "bbb-fie"
          - ...
      - name: Task2
        command: "rm -f {{ item.key2 }}"
        with_items:
          - key1: "aaa"
            key2: "aaa-file"
          - key1: "bbb"
            key2: "bbb-fie"
          - ...
```

In this case, I suggest you to define a variable with your list, at play level for example :

```yaml
- hosts: app_servers
  vars:
    my_list:
      - key1: "aaa"
        key2: "aaa-file"
      - key1: "bbb"
        key2: "bbb-fie"
      - ...
  tasks:
    - name: Task1
      command: "cd /home/{{ item.key1 }}"
      with_items: "{{ my_list }}"
    - name: Task2
      command: "rm -f {{ item.key2 }}"
      with_items: "{{ my_list }}"
```